# What's the effect of Ubuntu upgrade on the session configurations?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade

If I upgrade through update-manager, will my current Gnome 'classic' session be reset to the default panel configuration, or will the system keep the current layout? Is a backup preferable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upgrades usually keep your settings. It's nice to backup just in case, but your settings are reused wherever possible.

Comment: What Roland Taylor MEANS to say is that you should always keep a backup just in case the settings (for some random reason) would reset themselves.  However, Roland is right, typically your settings should remain intact, and should be reused in the upgraded system environment.